# Include null values in SQL query

Tags: mysql

I have the following four tables in my database:

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| complex_id   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| complex_name | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| machine_id   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| complex_id   | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| machine_name | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| devices_id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| machine_id      | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| description     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| location        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| verification    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| rack_num        | varchar(8)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| section_num     | varchar(8)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| color_or_number | varchar(16)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| normal_position | varchar(16)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| pnp_id     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| devices_id | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| pnp_num    | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I am trying to get results formatted as follows (NULL values appear as blanks):

```
+------------+-------------+-----------------------+
| devices_id | description | pnpnum                |
+------------+-------------+-----------------------+
| 1          | ex          | 1234                  |
| 2          | ex2         | 2345                  |
| 3          | ex3         |                       |
| 4          | ex4         | 3456, 4567, 5678, 6879|
+------------+-------------+-----------------------+
```

Using the following SQL query,

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(pnp.pnp_num separator ', ') pnpnum
FROM devices
JOIN pnp ON devices.devices_id = pnp.devices_id
WHERE devices.machine_id = 1
GROUP BY devices.devices_ID
ORDER BY devices.description;
```

my results are relatively close, however, I am unable to include a device if it has a null pnpnum.

```
+------------+-------------+-----------------------+
| devices_id | description | pnpnum                |
+------------+-------------+-----------------------+
| 1          | ex          | 1234                  |
| 2          | ex2         | 2345                  |
| 4          | ex4         | 3456, 4567, 5678, 6879|
+------------+-------------+-----------------------+
```

What is it that I am missing from my SQL statement that will allow me to include null values?

Comment: Is your table set to default value NULL? Like: `pnpnum` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL

Comment: I believe you should use `LEFT JOIN` instead of a regular `JOIN`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN` because even if there isn't a match, it will return all the results from the left table leaving the fields from the right table `null`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I definitely would appreciate an explanation. SQL novice here..... Thanks :)

Comment: "If there is no matching row for the right table in the ON or USING part in a LEFT JOIN, a row with all columns set to NULL is used for the right table." ([Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)) // With a normal join, a row must exist in both tables or the row will be dropped, while with a left join, the row only needs to exist in the left table/collection of rows.